# i am not able to pass value from one page to another page using Sessions in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am a newbie in programming. I want to to fetch logged user id from database and store in SESSION and insert that session id in another table. I think I made my day but unfortunately there is an error which is driving me nuts. Any help would be appreciated!

Database `btrs` has table `booking` which have coulmn name

```
booking_id,customer_id,route_id
```

**dbConfig.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";      
$dbname = "btrs"; 
$dbuser = "root";           
$dbpass = "";               
$conn =mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

**Logincheck.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbConfig.php');
$error  =   ''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "email or Password is invalid";
    }
    else {
        $email      =   $_POST['email'];
        $password   =   $_POST['password'];
        $email      =   stripslashes($email);
        $password   =   stripslashes($password);
        $email      =   mysql_real_escape_string($email);
        $password   =   mysql_real_escape_string($password);

        $query      =   mysql_query("select * from member where password='$password' AND email='$email'");
        $count      =   mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($count > 0 ) {
            $row    =   mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from member where password='$password' AND email='$email'"));
             $id    =   $row['id'];
            // echo $id;
            $_SESSION['id']=$id;
            header("location: profile.php"); 
        } else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**booking.php**

```
<?php
include"dbConfig.php";
include "logincheck.php";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $from1          =   $_POST['from'];
    $destination1   =   $_POST['destination'];
    $query          =   mysql_query("SELECT route_id FROM route WHERE pick_from='$from1' AND destination='$destination1'"); 
    $row            =   mysql_fetch_array($query); 
    $route_id       =   $row['route_id'];
    // echo $route_id;

    if ($row!=NULL) {
        $query1 =   "INSERT INTO booking(customer_id,route_id) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."','$route_id')";
        if ($query1==1) {
            echo"very goodddd";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "good";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this a typo: `Logincheck.php` (uppercase "L") then in your script: `include "logincheck.php";`?

Comment: Since you're a newbie, here's a little tip for you. Don't bother using mysql_ functions. The MySQL extension is officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and fully removed in PHP 7. There is no active development on it and using it makes your code less future proof.  Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start session in `profile.php` file.

Add `session_start();` in `profile.php` or `booking.php` at top of line, before include dbconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

For every page where you want to create session variables and/or use session variables, you should start the very top of your code like this...

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you have to start session first.

So Use this code to start session.

> session_start();

Visit this url for more reference.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php